# wmode=transparent lightens the gray color in swf

Tags: html, flash

I am using lightbox++ to load images outside of flash in order to make that work I have to set

```
 wmode=transparent
```

in the object properties

But doing this lightens the gray color used in the swf..

Without adding wmode=transparent

[image]

Screenshot with wmode=transparent

[image]
Can anybody explain this behavior?

here is the whole code

```
<object classid="clsid:D27CDB6E-AE6D-11cf-96B8-444553540000" style="display: block" codebase="http://download.macromedia.com/pub/shockwave/cabs/flash/swflash.cab#version=7,0,19,0" width="100%" height="100%;">
    <param name="movie" value="site.swf">
    <param name="quality" value="high">
    <param name="menu" value="false">
    <param name="allowscriptaccess" value="always" />
    <param name="wmode" value="transparent" />
    <param name="allowFullScreen" value="true">
    <embed src="site.swf" allowfullscreen="true" wmode="transparent" menu="false" quality="high" pluginspage="http://www.macromedia.com/go/getflashplayer" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" width="100%" height="100%">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I found a hint to the solution on [this page](http://www.dmxzone.com/forum/topic/31232/)

this is what i had done to fix the issue

```
wmode="opaque"
```

(by default the swf is set to be on top of all thus we have to use wmode to decide how we want to diplay the swf)

http://kb2.adobe.com/cps/127/tn_12701.html